# Rank sufficiency concept in Finite Element

Tags: finite-element

From [section 19.4.1, Rank Sufficiency](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.Ch19.d/IFEM.Ch19.pdf):

> The element stiffness matrix must not possess any zero-energy
>   kinematic mode other than rigid body modes.
>
> This can be mathematically express as follows....

I have no idea what does this section about Rank Sufficiency mean. What is rank sufficiency in physical term, and why is it so important for stiffness matrix? If *rank deficiency* occurs, then what will happen to the stiffness matrix and the solution of it?

Comment: Isn't that the same as infinitesimal rigidity (which has a straightforward physical interpretation)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rigidity

Comment: @Kirill, would you like to elaborate your comment and show how it is the same with structural rigidity in an answer?

Comment: Well, for the rigid body modes e we have K * e = 0, right? If there were any other e' satisfying K * e' = 0 that would mean that there is another displacement vector with zero energy. But I guess physics tells you the RBMs should be the only ones.

Comment: @fpnick , you are explaining rigid body is the same as RBM, but my question is about rank sufficiency. The two don't connect

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting you correctly here, sorry. Are you aware of the fact that rank(K) + dim(nullspace(K)) = n for an n x n matrix K? If dim(nullspace(K)) is larger than the number of RBMs then K would be called rank deficient in terms of the script you posted. At least that's the way I understand it.